# Testing traefik on play-with-docker.com

Tags: docker, traefik

I tried to test and play around with **traefik** on `play-with-docker.com` before running it on my own private server.

However i could not get a simple example with 2 containers to work, see my `docker-compose.yml` file below. The containers both starts with `up` without any errors in their logs. I can see the *traefik dashboard* on port 80 with the subpath `/traefik`. But i cannot see *dozzle* on port 80 with the subpath `/dozzle`.

What is wrong with my configuration?
Or does *traefik* not work properly on `play-with-docker.com` at all?

If i uncomment the `ports` section, i can see dozzle on port 8083 - but that is not what i want, then i am bypassing traefik...

Thanks for all hints...

```
---
version: '3.5'

networks:
  proxy:
    name: proxy
    driver: bridge
  web:
    name: web
    driver: bridge

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--logLevel=INFO"
      - "--api"
      - "--defaultentrypoints=http"
      - "--docker"
      - "--docker.watch"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - proxy
      - web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.backend=traefik"
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/traefik"
    - "traefik.port=8080"
    - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"

  dozzle:
    image: amir20/dozzle
    container_name: dozzle
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    command:
      - "--level=DEBUG"
      - "--base=/dozzle"
      - "--addr=:8083"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    # ports:
    #   - 8083:8083
    networks:
      - proxy
    labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.backend=dozzle"
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/dozzle"
    - "traefik.port=8083"
    - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
```

**EDIT 13.07.2019 - additional informations**

I tried a simplified version of the compose file on my local machine with Docker Toolbox. Still the same issue. If i am on `http://192.168.99.100/dozzle` i get a blank white page and on `http://192.168.99.100` i get an `404` error.

This is the simplified version:

```
---
version: '3.5'

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--docker"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  dozzle:
    image: amir20/dozzle
    container_name: dozzle
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/dozzle"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
```

The blank page i get on `http://192.168.99.100/dozzle` contains a HTML page, if i am switching to source code view in the browser. However just a blank white page is shown. I assume that the relative links within the HTML code could not be resolved and therefore no css, js etc. could be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undersand the  dozzle command line option "*--base=/doozle*", the backend should be reached  through the path

> *:8083/dozzle*

But in your frontend rule, you remove / strip the "/doozle" from the initial request :

```
"traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/dozzle"
```

Thus, your should only use *PathPrefix* instead.

Comment: No success at all with this simple setup... either i am getting a 404 or a blank white page... maybe i should try this on a real server or VM...

Comment: traefil.port is still 8083? Because it was correct (according to your "command" options). Also : are you using basic docker or docker-swarm mode? If you are not sure, type "docker node ls".

Comment: Yes traefik port is still `8083`.
Maybe i have to `expose` the port in the compose file? Haven't tested yet.
I used basic docker, no swarm mode.

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to "expose" the port, since it is mainly a matter or documentation rather than a true port publishing. Anyway, I see several things to do here. First, try to publish on port 8080:8080 (like EdinTC said) but using traefik.port=8080. Since it is the default port, this may point out a pb in the "command" clause. In this case, you will have to maintain the "pathPrefixStrip" way, because this would mean the command options are ignored. Try also to have a look to  /var/log/messages (or any equivalent) : there may be some hints there.

Comment: I stripped the compose file down and changed the labels to `traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/dozzle`and `traefik.port=8080`. Still no luck, if i am going to `/dozzle` i get a blank white page, but no `404`

Comment: last of my ideas : though it is a swarm feature (according to me), this has to be tried anyway. A a section "deploy" at the same lever of the "labels" one, and put the "labels" section under / inside it (with proper indentation)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works now. Thanks for all hints. Maybe i changed to many options at the same time ;-(

This compose file works:

```
---
version: '3.5'

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--docker"
      - "--logLevel=INFO"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  dozzle:
    image: amir20/dozzle
    container_name: dozzle
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - traefik
    command:
      - "--base=/dozzle"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/dozzle"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
```

Now i see Dozzle on `http://192.168.99.100/dozzle`, which forwards for example to `http://192.168.99.100/dozzle/container/9b03de0e20a8`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the ports part of your traefik service:

```
ports:
  - '80:80'
  - '443:443'
  - '8080:8080'
```

Then for you Dozzle try this:

```
- traefik.port=80
```

This might be a personal thing but I always use the 'web' network as an external one.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, Dozzle will listen on a different port using the addr paramater; so with traefik 2.0 this combination works

```yaml
  # Dozzle - Real-time Docker Log Viewer
  dozzle:
    hostname: 'dozzle'
    container_name: dozzle
    image: amir20/dozzle:latest
    environment:
      - 'PGID=${ID}'
      - 'PUID=${ID}'
      - 'TZ=${TZ}'
      - 'UMASK=022'
      - DOZZLE_LEVEL=info
      - DOZZLE_TAILSIZE=300
    # - DOZZLE_FILTER="status=running"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - proxy
    command:
      - "--addr=:9999"
    security_opt:
      - 'no-new-privileges:true'
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:9999:9999'
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'  # Use Docker Socket Proxy instead for improved security
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - 'traefik.docker.network=proxy'
      - 'dockupdater.enable=true'
      ## HTTP Routers
      - 'traefik.http.routers.dozzle-rtr.entrypoints=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.dozzle-rtr.rule=Host(`dozzle.${DOMAIN}`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.dozzle-rtr.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.dozzle-rtr.tls.certresolver=dns-cloudflare'
      ## Middlewares
      - 'traefik.http.routers.dozzle-rtr.middlewares=chain-authelia@file'
      ## HTTP Services
      - 'traefik.http.routers.dozzle-rtr.service=dozzle-svc'
      - 'traefik.http.services.dozzle-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=9999'
```